# Adding cinnamon to my coffee makes it stop whirling much faster: Why is thats?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, everyday-life

When I stir my coffee in a cup, the fluid spins a long time, but when I pour cinnamon into the cup, the spinning fluid slows and stops very rapidly - why?

Comment: Is the cinnamon a viscous liquid by any chance?

Comment: Cinnamon is a powder that is swimming on the coffees surface at the first time. So who knows, is the whirling stopped under the surface. IF the powder gets distributed in your body the powder makes the fluid swirling around the powder and this turbulences slow down the whirling coffee. Perhaps it is a right thought or perhaps not. Anyway it is a comment and not a founded by experiments answer.

Comment: SOmeone is having way too much fun applying ridiculously inappropriate tags to this question.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I heard that physicists are famous for their humor

Comment: @HolgerFiedler; I'm with you. I suspect the coffee below is still spinning.

Answer (score 1):

Pouring anything into the cup adds mass but doesn't add angular momentum.  Conservation (plus friction between fluid and cinnamon) of angular momentum requires the new total mass to rotate slower than the original contents.